# How does offline mode impact Anno 2070?

Tags: anno-2070, drm

Anno 2070 apparently has online and offline modes, and I'm wondering how those modes are different.  I found some discussion of [what you can't do in offline mode](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/626105-anno-2070/61143679), but having not yet played the game those specifics weren't very helpful for me.

Basically I'm wondering about whether the online mode adds legitimate multiplayer-like content/gameplay, and whether offline mode is artificially restricted as a form of DRM.  (Ie. am I *punished* for playing offline, or am I just playing by myself?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The biggest thing I discovered is you can't use your Ark upgrades. Which is rather sad. Just when I think Ubisoft is doing better, I discover they just secretly sabotage the game in a less obvious way.

I mean yes the game can be played without the Ark upgrades but they are significant. Even if you research them within the game you're playing, it won't let you equip it. So you miss out on powerful global buffs to your buildings/units. I could understand disabling the persistent Ark inventory, but not the ability to equip the items entirely.

So to answer your question: **Yes, you do get "punished".**

In my opinion, you shouldn't, but that's how the game is put together.