# How do you obtain the ark upgrade Comprehensive Environmental Regulations?

Tags: anno-2070

I'm testing ark item stacking and I'm trying to obtain a copy of the item "Comprehensive Environmental Regulations" (Eco building maintenance reduced by some %, The icon is a house with the three-bar maintenance icon overlaid on it).

How do you obtain this item?

Or even better, can you link a save-game with this item?

**Update:** It appears that this item is a quest reward from Chapter 3, Mission 1: On Hostile Terrain. However, as far as I am aware you are not able to take ark upgrades from campaign mode into continuous mode. Is there any way to obtain this item in continuous mode?

Comment: I'll load it up tonight and see if it's possible to get; it may be a campaign-only item, though.

Comment: Don't ark upgrades carry over (with Ark Storage enabled)? Is it possible to make a continuous game on the easiest setting (without opponents) and building a large number of academies in your tech city to get w/e ark upgrade you need?

Comment: I've rolled the NPC's inventories hundreds of times in a continuous game now, and I can't get any of the relevant 2-star upgrades in this category to spawn.  I believe they aren't available in continuous, sadly.

Comment: Would it be possible to test your stacking with the Eco-specific ark upgrade + the generic ark upgrade for this category?  I've seen both of those loads of times now.

Comment: just curious Iain does the solution need to work in multiplayer mode??

Comment: It doesn't. I'm pretty familiar with memory editing, but I think the state of your ark is saved server-side even in campaign mode. Regardless, while common general-purpose memory editing tools are really good at fiddling numbers, they're not very good at all at adding items to collection types - which I strongly suspect is how warehouse inventories are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't buy the 12% reduction in any mode that lets you get them into your Ark for continuous/multiplayer. The best you can buy is **Environmental Regulations** (-10% Eco building maintenance) from NPCs. However, you could stack this in the one-star upgrade row with **Low Wage Regulations** (-8% building maintenance) for an 18% total reduction.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to get the 12% in continuous from missions random missions you cannot get them from shops at least i have yet to see them but i just got one from shamus green after i built his monument by doing a mission 12% maintenance on all eco buildings then i have a 1 star 10% and a 1 star 8% from all for a total of 30% maintenance reduction on all eco buildings im hoping to get a 12% from Tycons when i make the monument for them and get 30% on them to OP much :)

Comment: Would you possibly be able to upload your save somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be possible. I have done similar things in different games. What you might need to do is to download [cheat engine](http://cheatengine.org/). After that it sounds a little bit complicated but its really not that hard.

Tutorial of cheat engine will teach you what a memory address is (its really simple just finish the life tutorial (30 seconds tutorial) )

You must find the memory address of item.
Just save when you are about to finish the mission and get your item. Afterwards just drop your item and check if the state has changed pick up the item and see what states have changed (if this is impossible you can do other things just do something to change item state) . You should end up with few memory addresses that have changed after you do this for a few - to many times. (there are ways to be more proficient with this so if you are having a hard time ask me for hints)

after you have 3-6 memory addresses save them in cheat engine table (ctr+s if i recall correctly)
remember the values of the memory addresses. (write them down, there is another way but it might crash game during loads so this is safer)

after you do this load your game that you want to have the  item in. your memory addresses should change to something different- change them back to the ones you've seen before and alt tab back into the game. if game crashes make a sad face, and next time avoid changing all of the addresses leaving one unchanged. If the game crashes again leave another address unchanged until it doesnt crash.

If game doesnt crash but you still dont have the item try two things.
First saving and loading the game.
second freezing the values so they cannot change once you alt tab back into your game.

if done correctly this should work
save your game and you should have the item next time you load even if you turn off cheat engine.

I hope it works. Tell me if you are confused about anything or worried about the program. :)

Comment: Futzing with memory addresses, with an online game, sounds pretty much like a permanent ban.

Comment: @fbueckert I forgot to mention that this will only work in the single player mode. It wont even result in a ban it will just not work online. This game has a single player mode so I was thinking that's what the question refers too. (it might work on multiplayer games that you host a server for but there it wouldn't result in a ban anyways)

Comment: The problem is that Anno 2070 isn't really meant to be played offline.  Doing so results in some major kneecapping.  See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46630/20456).  This applies even if you're playing single player continuous.

Comment: @fbueckert This person is testing something so he might still find this information useful. I was just trying to help him out.